# How can I know what part of RTF syntax is wrong

Tags: c#

an RTF is getting built and passed into some methods and finally getting passed to a text editor but something is wrong because the editor cannot parse it and instead of the correct text - NewYork in this case- it will show the whole rtf text but I have problem with finding out what is actually wrong with this RTF so maybe I can narrow it down and find out where is the place in code that is messing up the rtf tags,
in my example it looks like this:

> "{\rt\plain\f0\fs24 f1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss Microsoft Sans
>   Serif;}{\f1\fswiss Tahoma;}}\deflang2057\deflange2057 \plain \f0 \fs24
>   \cb2 NewYork \plain \f0 \fs24 \cb2}"

Comment: Should it start with `\rtf1` instead of `\rt`?

Comment: Yes that one is an issue but after I change that to RTF now it prints "f1NewYork"  instead of "NewYork", I wish there was kind of a Syntax Checker for RTF or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should start with `\rtf1` and you had a stray `f1` that should have been `\f1`.

```
{\rtf1\plain\f0\fs24 \f1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f1\fswiss Tahoma;}}\deflang2057\deflange2057 \plain \f0 \fs24 \cb2 NewYork \plain \f0 \fs24 \cb2}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your RTF is short you may eliminate parts of it until you identify the error place.

The way I build/correct RTF code is by editing in Word (or WordPad) and see what code it generates.

Comment: editing in word or wordpad?  How do you mean I should do it?  Thanks